# ffmpeg upgrade fails due to nettle no longer compatible with highSierra

Tags: high-sierra, video, homebrew, youtube

I use HighSierra 10.13.6 on my Mac.

When trying to upgrade youtube-dl, the process also tries to update ffmpeg which fails because of a library called "nettle". As a result of this, ffmpeg was removed from my macOS and I cannot install it again.

Is this library important to "normal" use of ffmpeg? Where normal means converting downloaded videos from YouTube and/or between formats such as mp4, mp3.

Is there a way to pass options to homebrew to tell not to use this nettle library?

If not possible, is there a way to tell homebrew that for ffmpeg library use a locally built nettle installation directory?

Comment: Homebrew tossed support for options, claiming to know better than the end user how they should be using their software.  So no, absent writing your own formula, you can't specify compile-time options any longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers have noted, Homebrew no longer supports High Sierra.

While I suspect you will eventually want to switch to MacPorts, you could also download a static build of ffmpeg from https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/ and drop it in `/usr/local/bin`. These self-contained "static" binaries include all of the library code they need to run.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew [release notes for 2.6.0](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/) say that High Sierra is unsupported.

If you are stuck on old versions of OSX then I would look at [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) which does provide ports for many cases going back to Tiger. [nettle](https://ports.macports.org/port/nettle/summary) and [ffmpeg](https://ports.macports.org/port/ffmpeg/summary) seem to have a built version available for Leopard to BigSur. Although I would note that due to all the possible variants of ffmpeg (all the different libraries it can use) Macports might have to compile that or your machine.

Comment: To avoid ffmpeg compiling itself locally with MacPorts, use the +gpl2 variant. This is effectively what you’d get with Homebrew anyway.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy or just give no variants on the command line so does the default. However I mentioned that as I don't know if nettle is used by default

Comment: I believe it needs to be specified, because it so happens this came up in a Hacker News discussion recently. Someone's copy of MacPorts was trying to build ffmpeg from source when they didn't specify the `+gpl2` varient. It's of course possible they'd specified a default varient or some such.